# Concatenating two bit patterns

Tags: c, bit

I need to merge two variables. They both are unsigned ints.

- First: 11000000
- Second: 11111010000

Desired output:
11011111010000

In words: I need to put all the 1 followed by one 0 (in first number) in front of the whole second number. The only think that come to my mind is, to bit shift the first number to the left as many as the length of the second is. And than sum it. But i don't know the length. Though it probably could be found, isn't there a better easier way?

Thx

Comment: First of all: what if the concatenated bit pattern doesn't fit inside an `int`?

Comment: That will not happen, the secound number will always be smaller, so it will fit.

Comment: I don't follow. If `first` is 20 bits and `second` is 15 bits, both fit into an `int`. But the result will not. Using a type larger than `int` isn't really an answer as I can simply use larger numbers as well. So, what do you want to happen if the result won't fit into the type of `first` and `second`?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, it will be assured that the result will fit into an int as well. I am counting with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bit shift the first to the right until you have a series of 1's with no trailing 0.
then bit shift it to the left for the "length" of the second plus 1 (really the amount of bits after and including the first 1)
and then OR them together, don't sum or else bugs could arise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which runs in constant time:

You can compute the position of the first 1-bit of x by (int)(log(x)/log(2)).

Furthermore, you can compute the number of trailing zeros of x by a neat trick shown here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightMultLookup

Hence, your program might look something like this:

```
int x, y;
int lookuptable[32] = { 0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25,
                        17, 4, 8, 31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 
                        12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9 };

int tail_x = lookuptable[(((x & -x) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
int size_y = (int)(log(y) / log(2)) + 1;

if (tail_x - size_y <= 0) {
        x <<= size_y - tail_x + 1;
} else {
        x >>= tail_x - size_y - 1;
}       

x |= y;
```

Now, x contains the result of appending y to x as specified by the OP. Note that you need slight adjustments for non 32-bit machines.

Comment: so for a x = 00001100
size_x would be 4,
x to the left 5 is 110000000

not what op wants, do you have a method of detecting the first 0 after a 1?

Comment: Oops, I should have read the answer more carefully. Will edit my post to include a correct solution.

Comment: ok i think this got edited after i commented, so now it just moves x to the right the length of y and then or's it, theres no trimming of everything after the first "falling edge" or 1 to 0 transition.

Comment: looks good, while checking x&-x does it need to be cast to a float, also if x is 0 the answer will be -127 right?

Answer (score 0):

Determining if an integer is a power of 2

unsigned int v; // we want to see if v is a power of 2
bool f;         // the result goes here

f = (v & (v - 1)) == 0;
Note that 0 is incorrectly considered a power of 2 here. To remedy this, use:
f = v && !(v & (v - 1));

so to see if v is 1 less than a power of 2 we add one to v
(v + 1) & v) == 0

(copy + 1) & copy) != 0

so using Jon's answer and replaceing copy!=0 with (copy + 1) & copy) != 0
will trim until theres a int with a series of 1's at the end.
copy's scope will need to be outside of that for loop,
and the result will be (copy << (cBitsFirst + 1)) | second;

```
unsigned int first, second; // initialize these somehow
unsigned int result = 0;
int cBitsFirst = 0;
unsigned int copy;
for (copy; (copy + 1) & copy) != 0; copy >>= 1) {//stop when there is series of 0's followed by a series of 1's
    ++cBitsFirst;
}

result = (copy << (log2(second)+1) | second;//the plus one gives the 0 back
```